# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 authentication failed (#5.7.1)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-mail

i am making an auto send email java project using javamail api. when i send this mail using smtp.gmail.com host, it works. But when i use my own host server mail.sitename.com...it shows exception..my username and password are right. Please anyone help me to sort out this problem...
Exception is:-

```
    javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 authentication failed (#5.7.1)

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:826)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:761)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:685)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.zenga.servlet.MailNotification.sendMail(MailNotification.java:130)
    at com.zenga.servlet.MailNotification.doPost(MailNotification.java:45)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Codes:---

a) i am using DAO pattern for data fetching for to(email id ) purpose
b) a jsp file to take start and limit to fetch no of connection to those i am gonna send emails..
c) Servlet file is given below...

```
package com.zenga.servlet;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.*;
import com.sun.mail.util.MailSSLSocketFactory;
import com.zenga.dao.DaoFactory;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class send
 */
@WebServlet("/send")
public class MailNotification extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HashMap<String, String>list =   new HashMap<String, String>();
        Set<?> set      =   null;
        Iterator<?> itr =   null;
        int start   =   0;
        int limit   =   0;
        Map.Entry<String, String> me = null;
        try {
            DaoFactory dao  =   DaoFactory.getDao();
            start   =   Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("start"));
            limit   =   Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("end"));
            list    =   dao.insertLimit(start,limit);
            set     =   list.entrySet();
            itr     =   set.iterator();

            while(itr.hasNext()) {
                me  =   (Map.Entry<String, String>)itr.next();
                sendMail(me.getKey(),me.getValue(),request,response);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    private void sendMail(String toUsername, String to,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

       final String from        =   "xyz@sitename.com";
       final String subject     =   "a subject";
       final String password    =   "password";
       final String host        =   "mail.sitename.com";
         String msg         =    getMessage(toUsername);

            //Set the host SMTP address

                  /*MailSSLSocketFactory socketFactory= new MailSSLSocketFactory();
            socketFactory.setTrustAllHosts(true);

            Properties properties=System.getProperties();
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
            properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
            properties.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
            //properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.socketFactory", socketFactory);
             properties.put("mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable","true");


        //  properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable","false");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust",host);
            properties.put("mail.protocol.ssl.trust", host);
            properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
                    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                    "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            */ 

            Properties properties=System.getProperties();
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host",host);
            properties.put("mail.smtp.user",from);
            properties.put("mail.smtp.password",password);
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port","587");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
        //  properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
                properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable","false");
                properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","false");

            Authenticator auth = new Authenticator(){
                public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(from,password);
                }
            };
            Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,auth);
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            try{
                // create a message

                MimeMessage message=new MimeMessage(session);

                // set the from and to address
              //  InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                //InternetAddress addressTo   = new InternetAddress(to);
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));

                // Setting the Subject and Content Type
                message.setSubject(subject);

                // create and fill the first message part
                MimeBodyPart msgBodypart = new MimeBodyPart();

                msgBodypart.setText(msg,"ascii","hmtl");


                // create the Multipart and add its parts to it
                Multipart multipart=new MimeMultipart();
                multipart.addBodyPart(msgBodypart);
                // add the Multipart to the message
                message.setContent(multipart);
                // set the Date: header
                message.setSentDate(new Date());

                        Transport.send(message);
                        success++;


            }
            catch(MessagingException me)
            { 
                failed++;
                me.printStackTrace();
            }
     }



    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
}
```

I have tried everything that is in comment as well but nothing worked. i read many stackoverflow examples and no one is solving it correctly.

Comment: Is the username in the format of `username@host` or just `username`?

Comment: why username@host is required..as i have give it manually as you can see this in the  final String from        =   "xyz@sitename.com";...

Comment: and problem is authentication failure.... i use the same code just changing username=xyz@gmail.com and password="some_password" and host=smtp.gmail.com then the code works...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got the solution....
Sometimes javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 authentication failed (#5.7.1) occurs when host does not authenticate a user upto a limit using code...as i called the host to send the mail to approax 500 users at one program running.So the sendMail() called 500 times and got the server hanged. Hence it blocked my authentication from coding site yet can access using browser. 
 I figured out solution when i created a new account and then in coding i made a thread by which sendMail() will be called on a 10 sec interval and then send to 100 users in a go. The host was from a network solutions email login.
 Hope if i can give someone the solution for this sort of problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gmail account for emails (SMTP) then make sure you have **correct email password** in the application.properties file and also enable this setting 
**allow less secure apps** for your gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

In a project where I needed to send an email with an attachment containing test results that could be generated on different client machines, i used the following properties and code (the properties get translated to fields in a Settings object that is alluded to in the code below)

```
==================== Properties Section ====================
! Default Properties for the Email section of the project - others omitted

! The email provider may or may not require authentication - make sure to make the appropriate choices on the client
EmailSender = aUser@gmail.com
EmailPassword = unEncriptedPassword
EmailRecipients = me@gmail.com,she@gmail.com,you@yahoo.com,andAnyBodyElse@aol.com
EmailHost = smtp.gmail.com
EmailPort = 587
EmailAuthenticationRequired = true

==================== Code Section ====================
public class Email {

   public static void sendMail(String subject, String messageBody, String fileName) throws MessagingException {

      DDTSettings settings = DDTSettings.Settings();
      final String sender = settings.emailSender();
      final String password = settings.emailPassword();
      String[] recipients = settings.emailRecipients().split(",");
      String host = settings.emailHost();
      String port = settings.emailPort();
      boolean emailAuthenticationRequired = settings.emailAuthenticationRequired();
      String trueOrFalse = emailAuthenticationRequired ? "true" : "false";
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();
      Session session;

      // Use system properties and add some related to email protocol
      Properties props = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
      props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
      props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", port);
      props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "false");
      props.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack","true");
      props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", trueOrFalse);
      props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", trueOrFalse);

      // Create a session with or without authentication object as indicated in the settings.
       if (emailAuthenticationRequired) {
           Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
               protected PasswordAuthentication  getPasswordAuthentication() {
                   return new PasswordAuthentication(sender, password);
               }
           };
           session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
       }
       else {
           props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", sender); // Needed if not authenticating
           props.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", password); // Needed if not authenticatin 
           session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
       }

       // Setup the message in two parts, body and attachment then send it
      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
         //message.setReplyTo({new InternetAddress(sender)});

         // Set recipients
         for (int i = 0; i<recipients.length; i++) {
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                  new InternetAddress(recipients[i]));
         }

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject(subject);

         // Create the message part
         BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

         // Set the body of the message as html content
         messageBodyPart.setContent(messageBody, "text/html");

         // Create a multipart message
         Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

         // Set text message part
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

         // Part two is attachment
         messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
         DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileName);
         messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
         messageBodyPart.setFileName(source.getName());  
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

         // Place the entire kit & caboodle in the message
         message.setContent(multipart );

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
      }
      catch (MessagingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for having a look on it But as i already mentioned in my problem that my code works great with smtp.gmail.com as host. Your solution won't help in my case. BTW i already got the answer as described above. :)